# Laravel test Mockery

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Laravel: 6.x
PHP 7.3

I'am wirte a Repositorytest. below is my code, how can I fix this error,

error

```
TypeError: Return value of Mockery_5_App_Repositories_PersonRepository::fetchOrNewPersonById() must be an instance of App\Models\PersonModel, instance of Mockery\CompositeExpectation returned
```

Repository

```
class ContactRepository implements ContactRepositoryInterface
{
    private $contact;
    private $personRepo;

    public function __construct(Contact $contact)
    {
        $this->contact= $contact;
        $this->personRepo= app()->make(PersonRepositoryInterface::class);;
    }

    public function updateContacts(array $datas): bool
    {
        
        foreach ($datas as $key => $value) {
            $person = $this->personRepo->fetchOrNewPersonById($value['person_id']);
            $person->fill($value);
            if( !$person->save()){ return false; }

        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

and

```
class PersonRepository implements PersonRepositoryInterface
{
    private $personModel;

    public function __construct(Person $personModel)
    {
        $this->personModel= $personModel;
    }

    public function fetchOrNewPersonById($id): PersonModel 
    {
        return $this->personModel->firstOrNew(['id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

..which implements a Model.

```
class PersonModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'person';
}
```

and

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contacts';
}
```

my testing code

```
class ContactRepositoryTest extends \Myname\Myapptests\TestCase
{
     /**
     * @test
     */ 
     public function test_can_update()
     {
         $personMock = Mockery::mock(PersonModel::class)
        ->shouldReceive('fill')
        ->shouldReceive('save')
        ->andReturn(true);
        $this->app->instance(PersonModel::class, $personMock);
        
        $personRepoMock = Mockery::mock(PersonRepository::class)
        ->shouldReceive('fetchOrNewPersonById')->andReturn($personMock)
        ->getMock();

        $this->app->bind(ContractRepositoryInterface::class, function () use ($contractRepoMock) {
            return $contractRepoMock;
        });
        
        $modelMock = Mockery::mock(Contact::class)
        $service = new class($modelMock) extends ContactRepository {};
         $service->updateContacts([ 
            ['person_id' => 3, 'address' => ' XXXXXX update address'],
            ['person_id' => null, 'address' => ' XXXXXX create address'],
        ]);
        
        $this->assertTrue(true);
     }
}
```

Obviously I am missing something. Other examples explicitly inject the mocked object into the class they are then testing. Laravels IoC is (should be) doing this for me. Do I have to bind anything?

Comment: `$value['person_id]` is missing a closing `'`

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your current example contains several issues. Besides that: what are you trying to accomplish with your test?

Comment: I will help you if you want, but you approach is wrong, you should not mock models it is waste of time and inconvenient. You should use an database or sqlite. Is that something you want, or do you feel like mokcing models and repositories to the end of days.

Answer (score 0):

Here you assign to `$personMock` variable the expectation object instead of the mocked class:

```
$personMock = Mockery::mock(PersonModel::class)
  ->shouldReceive('fill')
  ->shouldReceive('save')
  ->andReturn(true);
```

This the right way:

```
$personMock = Mockery::mock(PersonModel::class);
$personMock->shouldReceive('fill')
        ->shouldReceive('save')
        ->andReturn(true);
```